# How to find the text of a h1 tag html format with no link?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to find a text "**Text title here**" in script below:

```
<h1 class="titleClass" itemprop="name">
    Text title here
    <a class="titleLink" href="somelink-here.html">
        text link here
    </a>
</h1>
```

I use python beautifulsoup.

Comment: the code like answer from @Martin Evans , just add `.a.extract()` in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the whole `h1` tag, and then extract any links as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<h1 class="titleClass" itemprop="name">
    Text title here
    <a class="titleLink" href="somelink-here.html">
        text link here
    </a>
</h1>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

p = soup.find('h1', attrs={'class': 'titleClass'})
p.a.extract()
print p.text.strip()
```

This would display:

```
Text title here
```

Comment: I tried to use this script `params.a.extract()` and it worked.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of regex and BeautiFulSoup:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
for link in soup.find_all('a', string=re.compile(r'^text link')):
    print link
```

This will find all links starting with `text link`.

Comment: I want to find the text of the h1 and not link.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to `<h1>` and get the first string from the `.stripped_strings` generator:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> next(BeautifulSoup(html).select_one('h1.titleClass').stripped_strings)
'Text title here'
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.
just want to ask, what 's' params ?

Comment: @Tarjo: that's the string containing your HTML markup. I renamed it.